# Pyspark removing multiple characters in a dataframe column

Tags: pyspark, translate, regexp-replace

Looking at pyspark, I see `translate` and `regexp_replace` to help me a single characters that exists in a dataframe column.

I was wondering if there is a way to supply multiple strings in the `regexp_replace` or `translate` so that it would parse them and replace them with something else.

Use case: remove all $, #, and comma(,) in a column A

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.translate()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.translate) to make multiple replacements. Pass in a string of letters to replace and another string of equal length which represents the replacement values.

For example, let's say you had the following DataFrame:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([("$100,00",),("#foobar",),("foo, bar, #, and $",)], ["A"])
df.show()
#+------------------+
#|                 A|
#+------------------+
#|           $100,00|
#|           #foobar|
#|foo, bar, #, and $|
#+------------------+
```

and wanted to replace `('$', '#', ',')` with `('X', 'Y', 'Z')`. Simply use `translate` like:

```python
df.select("A", f.translate(f.col("A"), "$#,", "XYZ").alias("replaced")).show()
#+------------------+------------------+
#|                 A|          replaced|
#+------------------+------------------+
#|           $100,00|           X100Z00|
#|           #foobar|           Yfoobar|
#|foo, bar, #, and $|fooZ barZ YZ and X|
#+------------------+------------------+
```

If instead you wanted to remove all instances of `('$', '#', ',')`, you could do this with [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace).

```python
df.select("A", f.regexp_replace(f.col("A"), "[\$#,]", "").alias("replaced")).show()
#+------------------+-------------+
#|                 A|     replaced|
#+------------------+-------------+
#|           $100,00|        10000|
#|           #foobar|       foobar|
#|foo, bar, #, and $|foo bar  and |
#+------------------+-------------+
```

The pattern `"[\$#,]"` means match any of the characters inside the brackets. The `$` has to be escaped because it has a special meaning in regex.

Comment: For removing all instances, you can also use `translate`. Switching to `regex_replace` is not needed. I believe the following would do the job `df.select("A", f.translate(f.col("A"), "$#,", "").alias("replaced")).show()`

Comment: @Sheldore, your solution does not work properly. It replaces characters with space

Answer (score 1):

If someone need to do this in scala you can do this as below code:

```
val df = Seq(("Test$",19),("$#,",23),("Y#a",20),("ZZZ,,",21)).toDF("Name","age")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("NewName",translate($"Name","$#,","xyz"))
display(df1)
```

You can see the output as below:
[image]