# How to unaccent special characters in PySpark?

Tags: string, pyspark, unaccent

I have a spark df with a string column with special characters such as `áãâàéêèíîìóõôòúûùç` and I want to replace them with respectively `aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc`

As an example of what I want:

```
name        | unaccent          
Vitória     | Vitoria
João        | Joao
Maurício    | Mauricio
```

I found this example but it doesn't work for these special characters [Pyspark removing multiple characters in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766487/pyspark-removing-multiple-characters-in-a-dataframe-column)

I've tried to manually create this df but for some reason I couldn't replicate the special characters and a question mark `?` shows up:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[("Vitória",),("João",),("Maurício",)], schema= StructType([StructField("A", StringType(),True)]))
df.show()

+--------+
|       A|
+--------+
| Vit?ria|
|    Jo?o|
|Maur?cio|
+--------+
```

When I use the `translate` function this is the result

```
df.select("A",
          F.translate(F.col("A"), "áãâàéêèíîìóõôòúûùç", "aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc").alias("unaccent")).show()

+--------+--------+
|       A|unaccent|
+--------+--------+
| Vit?ria| Vitaria|
|    Jo?o|    Joao|
|Maur?cio|Mauracio|
+--------+--------+
```

Any thoughts on how to unaccent these special characters?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is in your IDE, not in PySpark.

My environment: jupiter notebook in VS Code (macos):

```py
df.withColumn(
    "unaccent", 
    F.translate(F.col("A"), "áãâàéêèíîìóõôòúûùç", "aaaaeeeiiioooouuuc")
).show()
```

results in a correct output:

```
+--------+--------+
|       A|unaccent|
+--------+--------+
| Vitória| Vitoria|
|    João|    Joao|
|Maurício|Mauricio|
+--------+--------+
```

(spark.version = 3.2.1)